# How many bluetooth modules can be interfaced with Arduino UNO?

Tags: arduino-uno, bluetooth

At most how many bluetooth modules(HC-05) can be interfaced to Arduino UNO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two. One on the hardware UART (TX/RX pins with the `Serial` object). One on `SoftwareSerial` on any two pins you choose.

Any more than that and you will need more hardware UARTs.

Comment: You can create as many SoftwareSerial objects as you like, with a BT module on each, within memory, pin, and power constraints. But only one SoftwareSerial object can be listening at a time, which may make any others less than useful.

Comment: Also while you are sending on one reception is completely disabled (interrupts disabled) so you can only use one at once. As a rule of thumb, while you can *define* more than one SoftwareSerial you can only really *use* one of them. Personally I never even use one. I pick hardware that has enough hardware UARTs to do the job at hand.